# Mysql Update appox 1 lack User by using join from user_payment table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-update

[image: user and user_payment table structure are given as screenshot]

As I execute insert query this works fine for me and insert about 94,000 record in 12 sec. the query is give below.

```
insert into database1.user(username,id,password,date_created,last_updated)
select contact_email_id, user_id,user_password,rec_crt_date,rec_up_date from     database2.tbl_user group by contact_email_id;
```

but as I try to update the all the 94,000 user by using join with user_payment table using given query :

```
UPDATE database1.user as t JOIN database2.tbl_user_payment as t1 
ON t.id = t1.user_id SET t.subscription_type=t1.subscription_type,    t.subscription_date=t1.subscription_date, t.subscription_expiry_date=t1.expiry_date;
```

and as I execute this query i don't get any response or error. I waited for response so long(approx. 1 hour but i know i should not take more than a few minutes) but don't get any response.

Any Help is Highly Appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to understand performance, it is best to put `explain` before the query and understand the resulting plan.

This is your query:

```
UPDATE cvsurgeon.user as t JOIN
       jellyfis_cvsurgeon.tbl_user_payment as t1 
       ON t.id = t1.user_id
    SET t.subscription_type=t1.subscription_type,
        t.subscription_date=t1.subscription_date,
        t.subscription_expiry_date=t1.expiry_date;
```

Your image is hard to read, but I don't think it has an index on `jellyfis_cvsurgeon.user_id`.  The query really wants that index for performance.

Also, before writing an `update`, I think it is a good idea to write the corresponding `select`.  You'll probably have the same performance problem with the `select`, and you could fix it before launching a query that modifies the data.

Comment: yes  jellfis_cvsurgeon.user_id  don't have index, but if i want to do that without index. what should be apporx. time? although i am not a  db expert but in my opinion it should not take more 15 minuts.is there is any altenative way to update in my case.

Comment: Presumably, without an index, it will take hours to run the query.  There is nothing like actually running a query to determine the performance thereof.  When joining tables, indexes can make a big, big, big, big, big difference.

Comment: thanx for info. as i am novice to mysql, so can you please share idea on which table or tables column should i make index. if possible please provide syntax

Comment: thanks for valuable info.  index have done the trick and i have able to update data in 2.54 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t
   SET t.subscription_type = t1.subscription_type
      ,t.subscription_date = t1.subscription_date
      ,t.subscription_expiry_date = t1.expiry_date
  FROM cvsurgeon.user as t 
  JOIN jellyfis_cvsurgeon.tbl_user_payment as t1 
    ON t.id = t1.user_id
```